# Azure DevOps pipelines scheduler - can't Triger pipeline

Tags: azure, pipeline, scheduler

I want to schedule a pipeline to execute it every single minute - only for test purpose:

trigger:

- none

pool: test

pr: none

schedules:

- cron: '* * * * * '

  displayName: Monday till Friday starting at 7AM

  branches:

  include:

  ```
  - master
  ```

  always: true

Why this is not working? Ultimately I want to schedule this pipeline starting from 7AM Monday till Friday. Also try to test this and unfortunately it didn't start at all.

Comment: This every minute was only for the test purpose. Now I need to schedule a pipeline starting at 7AM from Monday till Friday so how the cron job should looks?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the shared  requirement the **CORN Expression** that You have to use either of the expressions   `0 7 * * 1-5` or `0 7 * * Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri` to trigger the job for every minute stating at 7AM from Monday to Friday.

You can refer this [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#cron-syntax), for more information about CORN expression syntax in AzureDevops.

You can also refer this [Blog](https://dzone.com/articles/schedule-azure-devops-pipelines-using-cron-job-expression) to Schedule Pipelines in Azure DevOps Using Cron Expressions.

Comment: This every minute was only for the test purpose. Now I need to schedule a pipeline starting at 7AM from Monday till Friday so how the cron job should looks?

Comment: could you please help with requirement details whether the job should trigger at 7AM only once per day till monday to friday or the job should trigger for every one hour starting at 7AM & ending 11PM every Day ?

Comment: Use this expression ``0 0 7 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *`` If you want to trigger the job at only at 7AM in between Monday to Friday.

Answer (score 0):

I want to schedule pipeline starting from 7AM only and from Monday till Friday
About the cron template:

mm HH DD MM DW

Your proposal is 0 0 7 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
Template have 5 general points starting from minutes and ending on Days of Week - on your example I see more than 5 points.

Comment: Please refer my above updated answer with the required changes.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70274883/15968720

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't precise enough.

Scheduled pipeline will start on Monday at 7AM and will run once. Next day the same pipeline will start at 7AM again and run once and the same till Friday. In my opinion it should look like that : * 7 * * 1-5 Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it is right you expression should be ``0 7 * * 1-5`` as i already stated above in my answer.  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70274883/15968720

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I wasn't precise enough.

Scheduled pipeline will start on Monday at 7AM and will run once. Next day the same pipeline will start at 7AM again and run once and the same till Friday. In my opinion it should look like that : * 7 * * 1-5 Am I right?

Comment: The above is not an answer, it is a comment that includes another question, so include it into the original question. Thanks.